# Installing Flex Builder Plugin on Eclipse 3.5 (galileo) Mac Cocoa 64bit

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way to get the Flex Builder plugin working on the latest Eclipse running on the Mac?

I've read that there is no hope with the Cocoa/64 bit version, but some report it works with the Carbon version.

I need the 64bit/cocoa version on the Mac in order to have access to the JDK6 libraries via the embedded maven support in the Eclipse IAM plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately Eclipse 3.5 is unsupported by Flex Builder 3.  There are a few bugs for this:
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-21025
http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/FB-21284

Please comment on those bugs and vote for them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. That worked for me. I have `Eclipse Galileo (3.5)` and `FlexBuilder 3.0`

Goto your Eclipse Installation (example my installation is `C:\eclipse`) and there to this folder: `C:\eclipse\links`

Open File or create `com.adobe.flexbuilder.feature.core.link` and type in this text:

```
path=C:/Program Files/Adobe/Flex Builder 3 Plug-in
```

In my case the word path was missing. After that restart your Galileo and it should work.